# Strang splitting for the NLS

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

The continuous cubic-focusing NLS is $$i \partial_t u(t,x) = -u_{xx} - |u|^2 u$$
A split-step scheme can be performed. Consider the linear split equation: $\partial_t u = -iu_{xx}$

It can be solved using the Fourier transform:
\begin{align}
\partial_t u + i u_{xx} & = 0\\
\partial_t \hat{u} + i k^2 \hat{u} &=0\\
\int_{\tau_{m}}^{\tau_{m+1}} \frac{d}{dt} \left (e^{ik^2 t}\hat{u} \right )dt &\\
u_{m+1} &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}[e^{-ik^2 \Delta t} \mathcal{F}[u_{m}]]
\end{align}

This completes the process for solving the linear part of the split system.

Now I want to do this using the *discrete Laplacian*.

**Question: What is the Fourier transform of the discrete Laplacian?** $\delta^2 u = u_{n+1}-2_{n}+u_{n-1}$. That is, instead of $|k|^2$, what is the Fourier symbol for $\delta^2$?

---

Discrete Fourier Transform:

$\hat{u}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}u(x_m)e^{-imk}$

$u(x_m) = \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\hat{u}(k)e^{imk}dk$

Comment: I don't understand. You are asking how to solve the linear Schrödinger equation with discrete Laplacian?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Oh no, sorry, I will ammend the post. I am asking what is the Fourier transform of the discrete Laplacian. In the continuous case, the multiplier is $|k|^2$

Comment: OK, in the discrete case you will need a discrete Fourier transform then. This should be specified in the text I suppose

Comment: Yes, it should have been written in the OP. I've just updated it.

I thought about using the discrete Fourier transform, but got confused in applying the definition to $(\delta^2 u)_n$. If you can explain in Answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3552098/8157) seems to be related but unfortunately it got no answers.

Comment: I've updated with the definition of the discrete Fourier transform that I was using in my attempt on paper. And indeed, I also found that post.

Comment: I answered the linked post. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
\begin{align}
\delta^2u_n&=u_{n+1}-2u_n+u_{n-1}\phantom{\int} \\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\hat{u}(k)\left(e^{i(n+1)k}-2e^{ink}+e^{i(n-1)k}\right)dk \\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(e^{ik}-2+e^{-ik}\right)\hat{u}(k)e^{ink}\,dk \\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2(\cos k -1)\,\hat{u}(k)e^{ink}\,dk,
\end{align}
hence
$$
\widehat{\delta^2}=2(\cos k -1).
$$